# Can't edit decimal type value in locals window VS2015

Tags: c#, debugging, decimal

Example C# code (in form load event):

```
  int a = 5;
  double b = 7.2;
  decimal c = 9.99m;
  string d = "test";
  MessageBox.Show(a.ToString() + "\n" + b.ToString() + "\n" + c.ToString() + "\n" + d);
```

Put a breakpoint on the messagebox line and run. Try to edit the values a, b, c and d in a locals window (or autos or watch). The integer, double and string values can be changed, but the decimal value (c) keeps changing back to the original (9.99m). Why is this? Possible bug? Or am I not getting something?

Comment: Did you try putting something like `c = 10.99m` in the Immediate Window?  It does sounds like a bug as I can change it in the Local Window in VS 2013.

Comment: Just tried in VS 2015 and I also cannot set the decimal in the local window.  When setting in the immediate window I get a `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException`

Comment: So It works if you put `c=default(decimal)` or `c=new decimal()` in the immediate window but everything else I've tried throws.  Very weird.

Comment: OK if I put `var s = 10.99m;` then `c=s;` in the immediate window it works.  So, I guess you can use that as a work around for now.

Comment: Even stranger is that I can then set the value of `s` in the local and immediate window, but still cannot set `c` directly.

Comment: Just sent a "frown" via VS 2015 about this.  Will update if I hear back from them.  You may want to do the same.

Comment: It is yet another VS2015 bug.  You can use Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick Use Managed Compatibility Mode as a temporary workaround, it isn't a very good one.  Use connect.microsoft.com to report the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, released March 30, 2016.