# Incorrect value when assigning to nullable DateTimes using Immediate Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var foo = new Foo
            {
                TheDate = DateTime.Now
            };

            Console.Read();    
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public DateTime? TheDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the line `Console.Read();` and using the Immediate Window in Visual Studio 2015, I observe the value of `foo.TheDate`:

[image: Observing the initial value]

Now I set the value of `foo.TheDate` using the Immediate Window to Christmas Day 1990 (any date will suffice, just using an easy to remember example):

[image: Assigning a new value]

I see the value echo'd back to me, so all looks fine. HOWEVER, when I now observe the value, the returned date is completely different:

[image: Observing the newly set value]

What's happening here?

**Edit:**
Further to the issue, if you use a regular DateTime (not nullable), and try this same example code, on attempting assignment using `foo.TheDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 25)`, the Immediate Window errors with a `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException` and message "Parameter count mismatch".

Comment: VS 2015 has some bugs in the debugger, like this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265706/cant-edit-decimal-type-value-in-locals-window-vs2015)  You should report this to Microsoft.

Comment: I tried it and changed the date to boxing day, then on reading back got this - "Internal error in the expression evaluator." !

Comment: @JustinHarvey Something very wrong here, see my edit at the bottom about what happens for non-nullable DateTimes, which is possibly worse - they are not assignable at all.